# why are contacts images stored as absolute URLs?

Tags: contacts, contact-image

I have made a copy of my civicrm instance i.e from http://www.example.com/example to http://www.example.com/example1 and when viewing a contact, the contact's image url is still pointing to the old sub domain http://www.example.com/example/civicrm/contact/imagefile?photo=firstname_lastname_6580lk2b77fb4029f5a00000035d9.jpg

which causes long response time to view a contact and also i get a warning (Warning: getimagesize(http://www.example.com/example/civicrm/contact/imagefile?photo=firstname_lastname_6580lk2b77fb4029f5a00000035d9.jpg): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in CRM_Contact_Page_View->preProcess() (line 170 of /var/www/example1/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View.php)

resource urls and directories have been updated, i'm on version 4.5.5

Note that this is not the case on http://www.example.com/example/

Answer (score 2):

The schema for contact records specifies that the image be stored as URL (`civicrm_contact.image_URL`).

As an historical matter, I don't know why this was chosen, but it does come with some trade-offs:

- If you write a UI in a different PHP stack, it's easier to share image uploads if they're URLs. For example, webform_civicrm accepts uploads using Drupal/webform techniques and then simply sets the URL.
- If you have a complex site that spans multiple domains, the contact images can be shared. Similarly, if you're migrating into Civi, you can import the URLs without rearranging the image files.
- It's trivial to include the image URL as a mail-merge token.
- If you migrate the Civi site to a different URL, the contact images break.
- If you access via APIv3, it's can be awkward to manage image data.

To fix contact images after migrating to a different URL, use SQL to perform a search/replace on field `image_URL` of table `civicrm_contact`. For tips on composing a search/replace, see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876762/mysql-way-to-update-portion-of-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Some of the performance problems are related to how the image url is resolved via the API.  For a good discussion see here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34929.0

Chris does a performance analysis : http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150121_M9_AX6/1/details/

One solution is to use the CMS for images and I found drupal handling / imagecache to be better for event images.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you move one instance to another please make sure you follow the below steps

http://wiki.civicrm.org:8090/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location

delete all the cache and rebuild the menu that should work correctly

Comment: these steps have been followed, note that this happens only to contacts with images. thanks

Comment: then in civicrm their is an table called civicrm_file please update the file path which hold the old file location change it to new location

Comment: Hi Ramesh, don't seem to find the file path in this table. thanks

Comment: hi Please look in civicrm_contact Table where you can find an column called img_url please update the path

Comment: Hi, i can see that the urls are not updated in the database but changing them to the current sub domain won't work either, have just tested by replacing the old sub domain with the new sub domain and got this error message:the image "http://www.example.com/example1/civicrm/contact/imagefile?photo=firstname_lastname_6580lk2b77fb4029f5a00000035d9" cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: Is this a bug? contact's images saved as absolute url makes it difficult to move the site